# What does "family" mean in the context of the asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, terminology

In the Rails guides for the asset pipeline, there's a reference to "family":

> Directives are processed top to bottom, but the order in which files
>   are included by require_tree is unspecified. You should not rely on
>   any particular order among those. If you need to ensure some
>   particular JavaScript ends up above some other in the concatenated
>   file, require the prerequisite file first in the manifest. Note that
>   the **family** of require directives prevents files from being
>   included twice in the output.

What does "family" mean in this context?

Comment: Just the group of "require" lines in your application.js files which resides on top of file (I guess)

Answer (score 2):

Family refers to the group of `require` directives that include :

- `require`
- `require_self`
- `require_tree`
- `require_directory`